# How do I know, via key event code, if the character just entered in a <textarea> is lower or upper case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to capture the character just entered into a `<textarea>`, but I can only get which key is pressed via key event like `keydown` or `keyup`, not knowing if it's lower case or upper case.

For example, when I input A or a, the event key codes for `keydown` are all 65.
I thought of using `val()` to get the string in the `<textare>` and get the last character of it, but that is too slow and memory consuming, since I want to record every keyboard event while the user is typing.

So is there a way I can simply get the last entered character?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I test if a letter in a string is uppercase or lowercase using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027224/how-can-i-test-if-a-letter-in-a-string-is-uppercase-or-lowercase-using-javascrip)

Comment: To clarify my question, it's not to judge a given character, but a key press event, that if it's lower or upper case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var p = $('#log')[0];

$("#textarea").on("keypress", function(e) {
  p.textContent = '';
  var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
  var character = String.fromCharCode(k);
  if (!isNaN(character * 1)) {
    p.textContent += 'character is numeric';
  } else {
    if (character == character.toUpperCase()) {
      p.textContent += 'UPPER case true';
    }
    if (character == character.toLowerCase()) {
      p.textContent += 'lower case true';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: Could you test for the shift key or caps lock key status?

Comment: Did you tried this? Well actually it does tell it, but it also lies in the same time...

Comment: @Kaiido can you prove any scenario ?

Comment: @RayonDabre you tested your code or you tested checking the status of the shift and caps lock keys?

Comment: I added the solution for Firefox, which always returns 0 when you ask for event.keyCode. now it works

Comment: @RayonDabre, Hi! This works greatly! Still, can I detect key events like "backspace", "delete", besides letters? We can use "keypress" to detect letter case, but if I use "keyup" or "keydown" to detect "delete", then I lose letter case. Is there a way I could both record letters input with cases and "delete"?   Thank you so much!

Comment: @Luke Chen, you can exclude those characters using their respective keyCode.
Kindly accept the answer if it has solved your purpose..

Comment: @RayonDabre, Hi again! I was hoping to generate user input logs like:   "timestamp1, user entered S",  "timestamp2, user entered t",   "timestamp3, user deleted t", like that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean about the shiftKey

```
var myObj = $('#myTextarea');

function isLetter(char){
  if ((char.toLowerCase() !== char) || (char.toUpperCase() !== char)) {
    return true;
  } 
  return;
}

myObj.keypress(function( event ){
  var text = myObj.val();
  var char = text.charAt(text.length-1);
  if (!event.shiftKey && isLetter(char)) {
    if (char == char.toUpperCase()) {
      console.log('Upper');
    }
    if (char == char.toLowerCase()) {
      console.log('Lower');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<textarea id="area1"></textarea>
```

---

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("area1").onkeypress = function(event){

        var code = event.which;

        if ((code >= 65) && (code <= 90)) {
            alert('Upper');
        }
        else if ((code >= 97) && (code <= 122)) {
            alert('Lower');
        }           

    }
}
```