# How to make a function that find the uppercase in a string and add a space

Tags: javascript, function, uppercase

How do i make it so the function will take in the param (breed) and search the uppercase letter and add a space there.

for example if i pass "goldenRetriever" as the param, then the function will transform it into "golden retriever"

```
function test(breed){
    for(i=1; i<breed.length; i++){
    //wat do i do here
    }
}
```

Comment: This smells so much like a homework assignment to me. Try searching, I'll start you off with the first solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027224/how-can-i-test-if-a-letter-in-a-string-is-uppercase-or-lowercase-using-javascrip

Comment: I wouldn't use a loop when .replace() with a regular expression can do it.

Answer (score 5):

You could [split the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) before each uppercase letter using a regular expression with a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), `/(?=[A-Z])/`, then you could join the string back together with a space and convert it to lowercase:

```
"goldenRetrieverDog".split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ').toLowerCase();
// "golden retriever dog"
```

Alternatively, you could also use the [`.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to add a space before each capital letter and then convert the string to lowercase:

```
"goldenRetrieverDog".replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1").toLowerCase();
// "golden retriever dog"
```

Comment: @Firefalcon1155 Because you're not returning the string. It should be `return breed.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ').toLowerCase();`.. see this example -> https://jsfiddle.net/L7m2x7uL/