# Make a mountain out of a molehill by replacing it with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to replace multiple words on a website with other words. That is, I am interested in finding all instances of a `source` word and replacing it with a `target` word.

Sample Cases:

**Source** | **Target**

Molehill  =>   Mountain

Green     =>   Grey

Google    =>   `<a href="http://google.com">`

Sascha    =>   Monika

Football  =>   Soccer

Comment: `ctrl-f`? can you do this in the code base?

Comment: You can write a program to search and replace using regular expression in javascript, another way to use some editor such as notepad++ and do ctrl+f in all files as mentioned above.

Comment: currently i am working with this for each replacement:

https://jsfiddle.net/p4Lmea6v/

but i need a lot of more replacements like in the first post said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the JS:

```
function replaceWords () {
var toReplace = [
    ["Green","Grey"],
    ["Google","<a href='http://google.com'>"]
];
var input = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
console.log("Input: " + input);
for (var i = 0; i < toReplace.length; i++) {
    var reg = new RegExp(toReplace[i][0],"g");
    input = input.replace(reg,toReplace[i][1]);
}
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = input;
```

};

replaceWords();

Comment: What if your word appears in an HTML attribute, or is a substring of an HTML tag etc? I recommend iterating through the DOM and replacing text nodes only.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat of a half answer. It shows the basic process, but also illustrates some of the inherent difficulties in a process like this. Detecting capitalization and properly formatting the replacements would be a bit intensive (probably utilizing something like this on a case-by-case basis [How can I test if a letter in a string is uppercase or lowercase using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027224/how-can-i-test-if-a-letter-in-a-string-is-uppercase-or-lowercase-using-javascrip)). Also, when dealing with text nodes, innerHTML isn't an option, so the google replacement comes out as plain text instead of HTML.

TLDR - If you have another way to do this that doesn't involve javascript, do it that way.

```js
var body = document.querySelector('body')

function textNodesUnder(el){
  var n, a=[], walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  while(n=walk.nextNode()) a.push(n);
  return a;
}

function doReplacements(txt){
  txt = txt.replace(/sascha/gi, 'monika')
  txt = txt.replace(/mountain/gi, 'molehill')
  txt = txt.replace(/football/gi, 'soccer')
  txt = txt.replace(/google/gi, '<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>')
  console.log(txt)
  return txt
}

var textnodes = textNodesUnder(body),
    len = textnodes.length,
    i = -1, node

console.log(textnodes)

while(++i < len){
  node = textnodes[i]
  
  node.textContent = doReplacements(node.textContent)
}
```

```html
<div>Mountains of Sascha</div>
<h1>Playing football, google it.</h1>
<p>Sascha Mountain football google</p>
```