# Check case of letter in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there another way to check for the case of a letter in a string? I currently use

```
let letter = String.fromCharCode(Math.round(Math.random() * 100/(100/26))) // sets letter to a random letter
if (letter.toUpperCase() == letter) {
    //insert thing to happen here
}
```

I apologize if there is another question asking this, I didn't see one when i checked

Comment: What "other" way are you looking for? Would the same check with `.toLowerCase()` be another valid way (then flip the condition)? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Does this also have to work for letters that aren't in the Latin alphabet (like your current solution does)? eg: Cyrillic?

Comment: @NickParsons Is there a better way besides using either of those

Comment: @NickParsons no, Just the english alphabet

Comment: @James that is not the case, I just tested it and it works as planned

Comment: It doesnt work as is, it has mismatched parentheses, missing a `)`.  Anyway - please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027224/how-can-i-test-if-a-letter-in-a-string-is-uppercase-or-lowercase-using-javascrip)

Comment: @James oh I see it now, I just tested it by rewriting it without the String.fromCharCode()

Comment: Just an fyi here, `100/(100/26)` simplifies to just `26`.

Comment: @usernotfound8 ... Why don't you want to rely on the most obvious and expressive solution of `value.toUpperCase() === value`? This will work regardless of the targeted letter ranges other the basic latin. And the only `RegExp`-based solution that might come close to the former's reliability would be `(/\p{Lu}/u).test(value)` where one makes use of the [`u`nicode-flag](https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode) which enables checking for any character's [unicode-properties](https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode#unicode-properties-p) … like e.g. an uppercased letter … `Lu`(`L`etter `u`ppercase).

Comment: @moonstar-x it would not, the first 100 gets multiplied to the Math.random to get anywhere from 0-100, then the parenthesis means that 100/26 would be ~3.846. then the random number which is now 0-100 gets divided by 3.846 to get a number 0-26 then it's rounded to a whole number to be converted to a letter

Comment: @PeterSeliger Im just trying to figure out if there's a shorter/better way to find the case of a letter

Comment: @usernotfound8 It does. Let `R = Math.random()`, given your explanation you're thinking of `(R*100) / (100/26)`, which is the same as `((R*100) / 1) / (100/26)`, given that [(A/B) / (C/D) = AD / BC](https://www.quora.com/How-would-one-simplify-a-fraction-of-the-form-A-B-C-D), it would equal `(R*100*26) / (1*100)`. Lower side gets simplified to just `100` and since top side is all multiplication, the `100`s get cancelled out and you're left with `R * 26`.

Comment: @moonstar-x due to javascript mostly following pemdas, parenthesis aren't needed

Comment: @usernotfound8 I'm aware that the parenthesis are not needed, I'm just trying to illustrate the example. Keep in mind that in this case, `Math.random()` can be considered a constant, and since multiplication is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), then what I said about the simplification is true. You might as well try it for yourself if you don't believe me, or don't.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const isUpperCase = letter => letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z'

console.log(isUpperCase('B'))
console.log(isUpperCase('d'))
```

Comment: OP's original code can correctly recognize Á as uppercase.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly You are right, though this answer is too. OP asked for detecting the case of letters from "Just the english alphabet".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which uses regex [character-ranges](https://javascript.info/regexp-character-sets-and-ranges).

```js
const whichCaseType = value =>
  (/^[A-Z]$/).test(value)
    ? 'uppercase'
    : (/^[a-z]$/).test(value) ? 'lowercase' : 'neither';

console.log(`The letter is in ${ whichCaseType('A') }.`);
console.log(`The letter is in ${ whichCaseType('a') }.`);
console.log(`The letter is in ${ whichCaseType('_') }.`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What does the dollar sign mean? And what does (regex).test(value) do?

Comment: @usernotfound8 ... `^` line start / `$` line end / `[A-Z]` a character-range matching a single character in between/including `A` and `Z`. Thus the two regex patterns are looking for a single character, each satisfying its range. The start and end checking is due to ensuring that `value` is just a single character and not a string with a length grater than 1. [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is one of the available `RegExp` methods which evaluate strings. Why didn't you lookup it yourself?

Answer (score -2):

```
letter = "a";
let check = (letter) => {
  if (letter >= "A" && letter <= "Z") {
    return true;
  } else if (letter >= "a" && letter <= "z") {
    return false;
  }
};
console.log(check(letter));
```

This might help!